# Sometimes in Safari the first click isn't sent to the popup

Tags: javascript, popup, focus, safari

I used different methods including "onclick" and jquery.

http://sky-walker.net/temp/test.htm

On Safari (for Windows at least), the first click after a popup appears (alert, prompt or confirm) isn't handled by the popup... e.g. in my test trigger a popup then hover or click on the checkbox... the first click doesn't register with the "ok" button...

Is there any workaround?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but...i confirm this. First click doesn't register on the popup, but it registers on the page.
As a workaround maybe you could give focus to the popup as soon as it appears